# Android emulator slow after restarting computer

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

After restarting my computer the Android emulator is very slow on visual studio 2015, but after a few hours of running it's back at normal speed.
While the emulator is slow I constantly get messages like process system isn't responding, settings isn't responding, launcher3 isn't responding.

**Emulator specs:**

Android 6.0 - API Level 23

CPU : Intel Atom(x86)

RAM: 1835 VM Heap: 128

Internal Storage: 800

SD Card: 100

Use Host GPU enabled

Anyone know the cause of this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally fixed it.

In my case, I have a laptop with an extra graphic's card.

After changing settings in the nvidia panel: Control 3D settings -> Prefer nvidia processor.

then

right click AVD Manager.exe -> execute with graphic processor.

That fixed it for me